# Unit Testing of framework 1.1 project with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Is it possible to write and run with Visual Studio 2008 some unit test and target a project written with framework 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it will be limited to the public API of the 1.1 assembly.  You'll need to reference the built assembly, you won't be able to include the project in your test solution directly.  1.1 doesn't support the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute either, so you won't be able to (easily) expose internal/friend members.